# ExtJS Grid, allow spacebar when filling input field

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am porting some really tough old HTML code to an ExtJS Grid, and unfortunately every once in a while some cells get their contents as pure HTML via ajax and put input elements inside the grid's cells.

In one occasion I end up with a mortal Textarea inside a cell, which looks fine, yet typing text into the textarea is not very convenient, as the "space" is not allowed, the grid simply ignores it.

[image]

I have already tried keyNav.disable(); and enableKeyNav = false; but neither of these help :(

Comment: ExtJS is not letting you insert a space between 2 characters or the spaces are removed from the content on loading the `grid`? Why did you need to tryout the `keyNav`? What happens when you press the spacebar? Is it completely ignored or something else happens?

Comment: Hi! It does not let me input a space character while typing. It is completely ignored.

Comment: can you please provide a bit more info? is this an editable grid we are talking about, and if so what is the config for the column which gives you problems. Also what do you mean pure HTML via AJAX? Grids are supposed to get their data via json or xml.

Comment: @clops What I can suggest is to query the data from the HTML, add it to an array and create an ArrayStore for your Grid/EditorGrid to consume.

Answer (score 0):

All works fine: (sample: http://jsfiddle.net/e6vTw/)

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', { fields: [ {name: 'company'}, {name: 'price' }],
            data: [['3m Co', 71.72], ['Alcoa Inc', 29.01], ['Altria Group Inc',83.81]]
        }),
        columns: [{
            text: 'Company',
            dataIndex: 'company',
            width: 200,
            renderer: function(val) { 
                return Ext.String.format('<textarea style="width:194px;" rows="4">{0}</textarea>', val); 
            }
        }, {
           text: 'Price',
           dataIndex: 'price'
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});​
```